# Android replace java executorservice and future with coroutines

Tags: android, executorservice, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have an app that uses EceutorService with Future to send messages to a remote service with socketes and process it's responses.

I want to replace this mechanism with coroutines, since I've red it's more efficient and light.

**Is there a way I can use a kotlin coroutine inside a java android app?**
if so, how can I implement it? is it with kotlinx?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Coroutines are built off Kotlin and are not able to be used in a Java application.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Answer (score 0):

You cant use kotlin coroutines in java.

But java has very interesting project called project **loom** in progress, once that is released, jvm will have fibers and all the goodies that comes with it.

Watch out this space for more info:
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main

Comment: I did some reverse engineering on an exisiting app, I decompiled their apk, and I saw they are using java and kotlinx coroutines together

Comment: Original source code of that app must be in kotlin then. Kotlin and java both runs on jvm, both the cases, code gets compiled to class files.
Kotlin code with coroutines gets compiled to class files, but for ex. `suspend` is a kotlin keyword which is not available in java.

Comment: in that app it looks like there is a package written in java (all the classes in that package are in java syntax) and a seperate package to kotlinx coroutines, and the classes in the java package imports and implements some of the kotlinx coroutines.